# i want display my function, but it doesn't display

Tags: wordpress

I write plugin and want to display my shortcode in wordpress, but it does not display.

here is my code in plugin

```
add_shortcode("box","feedback2");

function feedback2()
{
    $my='short';

    return $my;
}
```

in wordpress, i create page and write

```
[box]
```

Comment: the code works, i copy/pasted it into a project. 2 possiblites: there is a naming conflict with either box or feedback2, or something in your plugin structure is not correct and the code is not being loaded.

Comment: Any text that might contain short codes needs to be displayed using `do_shortcode()` in the template. Perhaps your templates are simply echoing out the text without actually running the short codes? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/